# Why can't current flow in a conductor with a potential/emf on one end and earth on the other? Is there a mathematical expression?

Tags: power, electromagnetism

Let's say I have a wire with one end connected to earth and the other end floating. Now let's induce a voltage/EMF of X volts into the wire. Considering the ground to be zero potential, why doesn't any current flow from wire to ground?

I have heard the answer "current flows in a closed loop and the airgap makes the resistance infinite in this specific scenario", and then my question would be: why does current only flow in a closed loop? Is there a mathematical representation/symbolic equation that shows this electrical property?

This question arose from this problem (to provide more context) "There is a pole/fence parallel to a 3 phase power line with some impedance and one of its side connected to ground. We were asked to find out the voltage in the pole." To find the above we had to consider the current flowing through the pole as zero and calculate the voltage effect from the mutual impedance. This is confusing to me because there is an emf due to the power line in this case which is what is being calculated and clearly there is a path to ground and why isn't there a current flow there.

Comment: The mathematical representation is a line integral.  Have you studied calculus???

Comment: _"now let's induce a voltage/emf of X volts into the wire"_ - how do you do that?

Comment: You may induce a current but not a voltage.

Comment: This question arose from this problem, to provide more context "There is a pole/fence parallel to a 3phase power line with some impedance and one of its side connected to ground. We were asked to find out the voltage in the pole." To find the above we had to consider the current flowing through the pole as Zero and calculate the voltage effect from the mutual impedance. This is confusing to me because there is an emf due to the power line in this case which is what is being calculated and clearly there is a path to ground and why isn't there a current flow there.

Comment: You should address concerns by editing your question, not the comments.

Comment: @Uwe Opposite. Voltage is induced. Current may or may not flow depending on circuit. Think of a transformer with open secondary.

Comment: @winny I have had a deep thought on this matter, it does not feel right saying that a voltage is induced. I have started to say that an emf is being induced rather than voltage which is generally used for voltage difference. Because there can be current without voltage difference and vice versa, but there can never be current without an emf.

Comment: @winny The magnetic field moves the electrons in the conductor. If the electrons are moved a current is generated. If you use a superconductor there is current without a voltage. The lower the resistance the lower the voltage.

Comment: @Uwe Again, in a transformer with open secondary, the magnetic flux created by the primary induces a voltage on the secondary with no current flowing. Please look at the formula for Faradays law of induction.

Comment: @RahulRaman You are correct, EMF in induced. It’s measured in volt. I use the term voltage a bit loose here.

Comment: @winny  in a transformer with open secondary you need a tiny current to get a  voltage on the secondary. This current flows within the secondary winding, not from terminal to terminal through the air. Of course all these voltages and current are alternating ones. Femtoampere is a current too. Some electrons need to be shifted from one terminal to the other and back to have a voltage at the terminals. If some electrons are shifted, a current is flowing. If you measure the voltage a current is flowing through the instrument anyway.

Comment: @Andyaka Calling in the heavy artillery here. Can you try to explain it in another way to Uwe?

Comment: @winny There is no charge smaller than a single electron. Faradays laws are not valid for fractions of a single electron. An electron per microsecond, millisecond, second or minute  is no continuous DC current.

Comment: @Uwe No *unconfined* charge smaller than an electron. The actual smallest unit of charge, as far as we know, is ⅓ of an electron, which is seen in quarks. Due to quark confinement, you can never have a free ⅓ electron charge, however.

Comment: @winny There is a parasitic capacity between the terminals of a open secondary of a transformer. To change the voltage of this capacitor a current flows through the secondary winding. The secondary winding with this capacitor is a closed loop anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does current only flow in a closed loop? Is there a mathematical representation/symbolic equation that shows this electrical property?

The full answer is "Maxwell's equations", but that isn't particularly intuitive or easy to understand. The simpler answer for most circuit analysis is "Kirchoff's Current Law".

However, it's also important to recognize that "can only flow in a closed loop" is only always true for *DC* analysis. Let's have a look at a simple AM radio receiver:

[image: AM single transistor radio]

Image source: [circuitdiagram.org - Simple AM Receiver](http://www.circuitdiagram.org/simple-am-receiver.html)

What's that on the left? That looks like a wire open at one end and connected to ground at the other. And from a DC point of view it is: if you try to apply a DC current to the free end of the antenna, it will remain near 0V.

However, radio waves will induce an AC current in the antenna, which drives the resonant LC (coil and capacitor) circuit on the left, which is tuned to receive the desired radio signal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had a look at ampere's circuital derived from Maxwell's equation, And it seems promising to have all my answers!

Comment: You can make current only flow in closed loops in AC if you include extra components in the analysis - e.g. pretend the antenna is weakly capacitively coupled to a signal generator - if you have a simulator, it probably does this.

Answer (score 5):

> Let's say I have a wire with one end connected to earth and the other end floating.

If one end is earthed, then the other end is not 'floating', but also connected to earth by the wire. Perhaps instead of floating, you meant 'available to make a connection to'. That would be called a terminal.

> Now let's induce a voltage/emf of X volts into the wire.

You can't, the wire is connected to earth. But if the wire has a finite resistance, then the terminal is earthed through a resistance, which means you can put a voltage onto it.

In order to put a voltage onto the terminal, you would have to connect it two a source of voltage. Voltage is always measured between two points. As you have specified a single voltage, that voltage is by definition with respect to ground. You therefore need to connect a voltage source, like a battery or power supply, between ground and the terminal.

> Considering the ground to be zero potential

That's what we mean by ground

> why doesn't any current flow from wire to ground?

Current flows along the wire, from the terminal, to ground. It continues to flow through the power supply back up to the terminal in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Current flows from Voltage source to Ground as there is some resistance in the wire which is connected to Ground. Kirchhoff's laws explain how the current flows. Kirchhoff's laws are based on law of conversation of charge and law of conservation of energy. You can perhaps verify it mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

Current doesn't only flow in a closed loop.  "Current" is the motion of charged particles.  The force that moves the charge comes from an electric field.  In electric circuits, we can say current flows in a loop because we provide a conductive path for the electric field to follow.

Your specific example of a power line next to a fence cannot possibly be answered without a vast amount of information - both geometric and parametric info about the fence, power lines, and surrounding soil - and a lot of processing power to simulate the transient electromagnetic effects.

We have formulaic estimations (more like guess-amations) that can give us ball park figures in every day practice.

To answer your first question, "inducing an emf" doesn't mean much when your question is this particular.  What kind of emf?  An emf from a battery?  Attached to what part of the wire?  Is it an emf from a neighboring alternating current?  What direction is the e-field that has been induced?  ... the point that I'm making is that your question straddles the fence between electrical engineering and electrodynamics.  Electrical engineers typically don't have a low-level understanding of the physics and resort to a high-level understanding of circuitry which often leads to incorrect conclusions.

There's too much to discuss and explain.  The answer is with maxwell's equations, which are the low-level building blocks of electrical engineering.